# HorizontalTextAlignment of Entry does not work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I declare `HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start` in my file to put right, but it does not work

```cs
Entry txtNifContribuinte = new RoundedEntry 
{ 
    IsEnabled = false, 
    TextColor = Color.Black, 
    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start, 
    HeightRequest = 40 
};
```

Comment: What is RoundedEntry?

Comment: it´s a customized entry @Bruno Caceiro

Comment: You should post the code of that entry. The problem is most likely there. If you use a  normal entry, is everything fine?

Comment: also does not work.I tested both ways and it does not work.

Comment: What xamarin version you have?

Comment: 3.4.0.1029999 V

Comment: isn't Start the default?  What is it doing that you think is wrong?

Comment: A screenshot would also be convenient.

Comment: _I declare ... in my file to put right_. Are you trying to right-align your text? Surely you should be using `TextAlignment.End` ?

Comment: `RoundedEntry txtNifContribuinte = new RoundedEntry` this can be a try. And if show `RoundedEntry` code, this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Now the `HorizontalTextAlignment` and `VerticalTextAlignment` properties work and the `XAlign` and `YAlign` were removed.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Well HorizontalTextAlignment is the most misleading property in the history of Xamarin and .Net (kidding)

For aligning the text you should use the `XAlign` property.

Something like this

```xml
XAlign="Start"
```

By the way i am curious about what the `RoundedEntry` is!!

Assuming its a custom entry you should use it like this

```cs
RoundedEntry entry= new RoundedEntry();
```